# Ferrum mouse.up doesn't work for click & drag method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cuprite

I'm writing a test which runs over Cuprite::Ferrum, where I need to click, drag and drop an element below another element on the page. Which works fine while I am doing it manually, but when i try to put it in a test, it almost work, but not quite.

I was unable to find he drag and drop API for Ferrum or Cuprite, so I created something like:

```
  def click_and_drag(draggable, droppable, offset_x, offset_y)
    x1, y1 = draggable.native.node.find_position
    x2, y2 = droppable.native.node.find_position

    mouse = page.driver.browser.mouse
    mouse.move(x: x1, y: y1)
    mouse.down
    mouse.move(x: x2 + offset_x, y: y2 + offset_y)
    mouse.up
  end
```

Pretty simple and works fine until it get to the mouse.up part. The element that needs to be picked up is found by the `draggable = page.find(element)`, and it needs to be dropped below the `droppable = page.find(element)`.

Everything is going great until the method gets to the `mouse.up` part, where the dragged element should be dropped and put in it's new place, but it just goes back to it starting position.

I am referring to the Ferrum doc https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ferrum/0.5/Ferrum/Mouse but cant seam to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the method works and all is well, the problem was with offset_x and offset_y, if you somehow find this and want to use it, keep it in mid, and keep them small!